# Concise way to filter a list in python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have two lists

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 

b = [0, 4, 5]
```

I need to make a list `c` from `a` and `b`, filtering `a` using indices in `b`. i.e., `c = [1, 5, 6]`.

I am in search of a one line code. Inbuilt, if possible.

Comment: `c = [a[index] for index in b]`

Comment: Also, `operator.itemgetter(*b)(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[a[idx] for idx in b]
```